# Gradle gives Error:(16, 0) Could not find method SourceSet() for arguments

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm getting an odd error(that doesn't quite appear on google searches) for a project im trying to work on, that tries to integrate a tess-two library.
Error points towards the project's gradle build file:

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}


SourceSet {
    main {
    manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
}

}
    allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        }
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}

    task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}``
```

Error:(16, 0) Could not find method SourceSet() [build_b529guzw2t1izai8d0rrxzfqm$_run_closure1@45c50f0d] on root project 'testprog' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
Open File

p.s.: I'm pretty new when it comes to libraries and programming sorta serious things, so if there's anything that's obvious and simple in retrospect that i'm missing, it's not quite unexpected, so please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a typo, its [sourceSets](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html) not SourceSet

Comment: Forgot to mention, already tried that
Error:(16, 0) Could not find method sourceSets() for arguments [build_b529guzw2t1izai8d0rrxzfqm$_run_closure1@2a131e42] on root project 'testprog' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: Also, your file seems incomplete if you have posted all of it, are you applying grade Android plugin?